# TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'policy_listener' | gevent-socketio

Tags: python, gevent, gevent-socketio

I'm new to python and I'm trying to test gevent-socketio examples with no luck.
I'm getting this error each time I access the html file. In this case, I'm posting the error reported from `live_cpu_graph` but `chat` has the very same problem.

Thanks for the help

```
Listening on port http://0.0.0.0:8080 and on port 10843 (flash policy server)
DEPRECATION WARNING: use `namespace` instead of `resource`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 390, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/server.py", line 159, in wrap_socket_and_handle
    ssl_socket = self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)
TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'policy_listener'
<Greenlet at 0x1cceb90: <bound method SocketIOServer.wrap_socket_and_handle of <SocketIOServer at 0x1dc0710 fileno=3 address=0.0.0.0:8080>>(<socket at 0x1dc08d0 fileno=10 sock=127.0.0.1:8080, ('127.0.0.1', 45823))> failed with TypeError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 390, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/server.py", line 159, in wrap_socket_and_handle
    ssl_socket = self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)
TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'policy_listener'
<Greenlet at 0x1cceb90: <bound method SocketIOServer.wrap_socket_and_handle of <SocketIOServer at 0x1dc0710 fileno=3 address=0.0.0.0:8080>>(<socket at 0x1dc08d0 fileno=10 sock=127.0.0.1:8080, ('127.0.0.1', 45824))> failed with TypeError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 390, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/server.py", line 159, in wrap_socket_and_handle
    ssl_socket = self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)
TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'policy_listener'
<Greenlet at 0x1cceb90: <bound method SocketIOServer.wrap_socket_and_handle of <SocketIOServer at 0x1dc0710 fileno=3 address=0.0.0.0:8080>>(<socket at 0x1dc08d0 fileno=10 sock=127.0.0.1:8080, ('127.0.0.1', 45826))> failed with TypeError
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have resolved changing this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Listening on port http://0.0.0.0:8080 and on port 10843 (flash policy server)'
    SocketIOServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), Application(),
        resource="socket.io", policy_server=True,
        policy_listener=('0.0.0.0', 10843)).serve_forever(
```

with this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Listening on port http://0.0.0.0:8080'
    SocketIOServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), Application(),
        resource="socket.io").serve_forever(
```

But I really don't know why. I hope someone can explain this.
Thanks.

Comment: The same problem occurred for a reason that I don't know, but this simple trick solved mine too.